# div position with different page width

Tags: html, css

I'm searching for a simple way to create a layout that is visually like this

[image: layout with page width>600px]

and that become like this with small page size

[image]

Do I have to create two ul with 6 li the first one and 2 li the second one and play with css rule for each ul positioning?

Comment: Although, you question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), you can find the answer using some responsive design frameworks such as [bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Comment: bootstrap grid seems to take all column of each row and show it all in one column but i need the last column of each row to be the last of the list. If I create two "container" for columns 1-6 and 7-8 i'm not able to align column 7 and 8 to 1 and 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your layout see attached code snippet.
I excluded your color layout to decrease build time.
Added 2 different background color to easy see the device width breakpoint.

The solution is being achieved by combining "CSS media queries" and "CSS Grid". Both are built-in within standard CSS.

- The "CSS media queries" provides mechanism to change css content based on media device width. In this case the breakpoint is set between 500px/501px.
- The "CSS Grid" is a grid layout that allows you to position divs based on your wanted layout.

```css
/**********/
/* Mobile */
/**********/

@media
only screen
and (max-width: 500px) {

  body {
    background-color: pink;
    margin-top: 20px;
      }

      .wrapper {
        display: grid;
        grid-row-gap: 20px;
        grid-template-columns:
        1fr
        ;
        grid-template-rows:
        repeat(8, 80px)
        ;
        grid-template-areas:
        "_1"
        "_2"
        "_3"
        "_4"
        "_5"
        "_6"
        "_7"
        "_8"
        ;
      }

    ._1 {grid-area: _1;}
    ._2 {grid-area: _2;}
    ._3 {grid-area: _3;}
    ._4 {grid-area: _4;}
    ._5 {grid-area: _5;}
    ._6 {grid-area: _6;}
    ._7 {grid-area: _7;}
    ._8 {grid-area: _8;}

    ._1,
    ._2,
    ._3,
    ._4,
    ._5,
    ._6,
    ._7,
    ._8 {
      background-color: white;
      padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
      font-size: 150%;
      margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    }
}

/***********/
/* Desktop */
/***********/

@media
only screen
and (min-width: 501px) {

  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }

  .wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-column-gap: 70px;
    grid-row-gap: 25px;
    grid-template-columns:
    1fr
    1fr
    1fr
    ;
    grid-template-rows:
    100px
    100px
    100px
    ;
    grid-template-areas:
    "_1 _2 _7"
    "_3 _4 ."
    "_5 _6 _8"
    ;
  }

._1 {grid-area: _1;}
._2 {grid-area: _2;}
._3 {grid-area: _3;}
._4 {grid-area: _4;}
._5 {grid-area: _5;}
._6 {grid-area: _6;}
._7 {grid-area: _7;}
._8 {grid-area: _8;}

._1,
._2,
._3,
._4,
._5,
._6,
._7,
._8 {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="_1">1</div>
    <div class="_2">2</div>
    <div class="_3">3</div>
    <div class="_4">4</div>
    <div class="_5">5</div>
    <div class="_6">6</div>
    <div class="_7">7</div>
    <div class="_8">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You would use the css media Queries. you would state:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
    [class*="col-"] {
        width: 100%;
   }
```

and replace the max-width with the desired max screen width for this to take effect. this is also assuming that each table element has its own class name and ends in 1 then 2 and so on. you can change it to div or just do each element by hand like:

```
.classname {
    width: 100%
  }
```

make note that the width of the element set to 100% will be the width of the containing element. for padding add this table in a div and set padding around it.

do some research in media queries in css for a better understanding of how it works.